# how to call contents of Div while navigating Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two dynamic Tabs with Google Maps in my Application...In that while creating tabs Dynamically Google map also initialoized(Map function called) after creating div tag for canvas...My problem  while i navigate to Tabs the i called div to show..it displays only the Canvas.....My Map not displayed...

i want to display the map content with last chebges in that map.....

My coidings are below...

```
 $("#content").append("<div id='" + $(link).attr("value") + "_content' style='width:100%; height:100%'></div>");
             var mid = $(link).attr("value")+"_content";

             tab1map(mid);
```

Map coding:

```
function tab1map(mid) {

       alert("Inside "+mid+" Map");
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mid),
        myOptions);

    $(mid).css("height","100%");

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });
  }
```

Navigate between Tabs:

```
$('#tabs a.tab').live('click', function() {



                var tabName= $(this).attr("id");

                var contentname = tabName+ "_content";
                // hide all other tabs

                $("#content div").hide();

                $("#tabs li").removeClass("current"); 


                // show current tab
                $("#" + contentname).show();tab1map(contentname);

               $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to trigger the map resize event, so it forces to render. Map won't render its tiles until it's visible.

User google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') to acheive this.

@see : http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map